# Why is tab bar not displayed correctly after being pushed animatedly from another view?

Tags: ios, ios8, segue, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I am pushing a tab bar controller into using a standard animated push segue on iOS 8, but here is what happens:

[image]

See the tab bar, it's cut halfway. If I invalidate layout using `setNeedsLayout`, `layoutSubviews` etc nothing works (I've even tried dispatching it after 2 seconds after view appears). If I tap home button and then come back, it re-layouts and displays correctly. This happens only the the segue is *animated*, if I make the same segue non-animated, the problem doesn't occur. How can I get rid of this behavior?

Comment: You shouldn't be pushing tab bar controller. Instead I would set it as root view controller of the main application window.

Comment: @Desdenova it's a one time thing for new users if not logged in. ALL my hierarchy depends on the view controller flow and there is a lot of stuff going on in initializers of the view controllers so I can't change the flow. I need a solution for the current scenario.

Comment: I couldn't produce this on a clean project. Seems like your missing part is equal with the status bar's height. Which makes me suspect `UIBarPositioningDelegate`. Need more info about your view controllers. Are you using a standard tab bar controller or is it a custom view controller?

Comment: @Desdenova it's a custom one but i dont remember implementing bar positioning delegate (i had it but got rid of it)